# Sheets Chart with 5 data ranges - plots not lining up with X axis

Tags: google-sheets

I have two pivot tables.
Pivot table one is the number of signups per date for 2019
Pivot table two is the number of signups per date for 2020

Secondly is a running cumulative total of signups, per year.

I've tried grouping the pivot tables by Year-Month-Day and by Day-Month

I'm trying to plot all 4 data sets on one graph to show year over year.

Each of the graphs are correct on the chart.  But they don't line up correctly with the dates on the X axis.

I tried to introduce another data set of all the dates on the X axis from Oct 1st - Aug 15 to see if I could plot the points for each day to get things lined up.  But that didn't seem to work.

[image: data]

[image: graph]

Comment: Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/138382/how-to-share-a-google-sheets-demo-spreadsheet/138383#138383) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: Here’s the sheet. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gvMnO5TWFBnpKAA3pd1VwXDd-Lzn9csQQE94OVR893w/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

[In your file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gvMnO5TWFBnpKAA3pd1VwXDd-Lzn9csQQE94OVR893w/edit#gid=440739081) sheet test_chart1 contains a bit rearranged data so that chart could see all dates (2019 and 2020).
Sheet test_chart2 is variation of chart which contains all days of the year and shows comparison of 2019 and 2020 day by day.